# Spring Redis Does Not Delete the Stream Entries

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, redis-streams

I'm using the Redis Template and I want to delete the entries of the stream after processing it. I used the below code but it didn't delete from the Redis Streams.

```
redisTemplate.opsForStream().delete("my-stream-key",record.getId().getValue());
```

Comment: did you fixed this problem? @Reg Reg

Comment: yes. I have fixed the problem

Comment: @RegReg - how have you fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

Redis streams don't support delete operations. Only trim() is available to fix the size of stream events by removing older ones.